# What is the conventional way to manage frontend dependencies with Sails.js?

Tags: javascript, gruntjs, sails.js, bower

I'm currently using **bower** inside a **Sails.js** project, I found the [grunt-bower](https://github.com/curist/grunt-bower) library very complete and useful. However, you still need sometimes to pick or exclude files manually.

So I'm wondering if it exist another **more conventional** way to manage frontend dependencies inside a Sails.js project ?

Thanks

**EDIT:**

For those who are wondering, here is my grunt task:

```
module.exports = function(grunt) {
  grunt.config.set('bower', {
    dev: {
      dest: '.tmp/public',
      js_dest: '.tmp/public/js/dependencies',
      css_dest: '.tmp/public/styles',
      fonts_dest: '.tmp/public/fonts',
      less_dest: '.tmp/dontpublish',
      scss_dest: '.tmp/dontpublish',
      options: {
        keepExpandedHierarchy: false,
        stripGlobBase: false,
        packageSpecific: {
          'bootstrap': {
            files: [
              'fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.eot',
              'fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.svg',
              'fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.ttf',
              'fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.woff',
              'fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.woff2',
              'dist/js/bootstrap.js'
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    }
  });

  grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-bower');

};
```

As you see, I had to include some files manually for bootstrap and I placed less and scss files in a "not published" folder to exclude them. It's no big deal, but I was just wondering if something better exist, or if I have a bad config.

Comment: Can you explain us better what are your needs? What kind of files you need to manage manually? In my experience a good grunt configuration could help you in this kind of tasks

Comment: You're right, maybe I don't have a good grunt config. I will edit my post.